# How to write jquery for play an audio after closing the colorbox popup

Tags: jquery, audio, colorbox

In my CMS website i am having the automatic colorbox popup at the time of my page load.By inserting the audio tag in my home.tpl file i can able to play an audio when a user clicks on my sites home page.Now i need to make the audio to play only after the color box popup closed.How to write jquery for this function.

[colorbox popup](http://www.bloggermint.com/2011/06/how-to-create-modal-subscribe-box-using-jquery/)

**code for audio**

```
<audio>
<source src="..." type="audio/mp3" />  
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made it to work by updated the script like given below.

```
<audio id="playaudio">
<source src="catalog/view/theme/pav_cosmetics/media/intro.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />  
</audio>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
      var expire = new Date();
        expire = new Date(expire.getTime() + 7776000000);
        document.cookie = "visited=true; expires=" + expire;
    $.colorbox({width:"620px", height:"450px", inline:true, href:"#subscribe"});
    $("#cboxClose").click(function()
    {
        document.getElementById('playaudio').play();
    });
        }

});</script>
```